# User.Claims becomes empty/null on closing browser tab

Tags: c#, authentication, session

After implementing on closing browser tab to call a logout API, I came across this issue on production mode:

```
result = (GlobalErrors)_licensing.RemoveSessionFromDB(User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Sid));
```

`User.Claims` becomes null/Empty, but when I log out properly from my application it isn't.

Any ideas or why this problem is occurring or if there is any optimal solutions?